# jquery select from inserted html

Tags: jquery

having trouble selecting from inserted modal html. dispatchBody won't' select or insert

```
success: function (response) {
        var result = omac.getJson(response);
 if (result.status.msg == "Success.") {var html = '<div class=\"modal right fade\" id=\"referenceModel\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"myModalLabel\">    <div class=\"modal-dialog\" role=\"document\">        <div class=\"modal-content\">            <div class=\"modal-header\" style=\"background-color: #428bca;color:#fff;\">                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" id=\"btnCloseModel\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;<\/span><\/button>                <h4 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"myModalLabel\">Reference Center<\/h4>            <\/div>                <div class=\"modal-body dispatchBody\">  <\/div> <div class=\"modal-footer\">      <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">CLOSE<\/button><\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>';
$(html).after(".mainBody");
            $('.dispatchBody').html(result.results.html);
        }}
```

Comment: first of all `if (result.status.msg = "Success.")` is an assignment, you probably want == instead. Otherwise, try giving more detail about what you're trying to do

Comment: not understanding the problem. maybe you could create a plunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess as to what you are trying to do here is:
insert the contents of var html after .mainBody, and set the content of .dispatchBody to the returned result

Which leaves you with an incorrect use of .after, it should be

`$(".mainBody").after(html);`

see http://api.jquery.com/after/ for details on after

If that is not your intent, update you question to reflect that.